# Table of Contents within Appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

My Minimum Working Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

\section{My First Section}

\section{My Second Section}

\begin{appendices}

\section*{My First Appendix}

Here I want something like:

\noindent My First Subsection ........... 1

\noindent My Second Subsection ........ 1

\subsection*{My First Subsection}

\subsection*{My Second Subsection}

\section*{My Second Appendix}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

So basically, I want a table of contents within My First Appendix, only containing references to the subsections appearing in this Appendix.

Comment: Just a thought: Have you tested the [`minitoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below I present another two options.

Here's one possibility using the [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package; simply use \DoToC whereever you want to generate the partial ToC:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\newcommand\DoToC{%
  \startcontents
  \printcontents{}{2}{\textbf{Contents}\vskip3pt\hrule\vskip5pt}
  \vskip3pt\hrule\vskip5pt
}

\begin{document}

\section{My First Section}
\section{My Second Section}

\begin{appendices}
\section{My First Appendix}
\DoToC
\subsection{My First Subsection}
\subsection{My Second Subsection}

\section{My Second Appendix}
\DoToC
\subsection{My First Subsection}
\subsection{My Second Subsection}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's now one possibility using the [`etoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) package; simply use `\localtableofcontents` whereever you want to generate the partial ToC:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}

\section{My First Section}
\section{My Second Section}

\begin{appendices}
\section{My First Appendix}
\localtableofcontents
\subsection{My First Subsection}
\subsection{My Second Subsection}

\section{My Second Appendix}
\localtableofcontents
\subsection{My First Subsection}
\subsection{My Second Subsection}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used your excellent DoToC comment using the titletoc package. While it is beautiful for subsections, in my appendix TOC, I also want the Sections, which are far too much on the left, making a lot of unnecessary linebreaks. Do you have any suggestions on how I could move the beginning of section and subsection more to the right?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with the `minitoc` package. In this case you will need to number the subsections (i.e. no star) to have them appear in any ToC.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{appendix,minitoc}
\begin{document}

\dosecttoc
\faketableofcontents% replace with \tableofcontents if you want a ToC

\section{My First Section}
\section{My Second Section}

\begin{appendices}
\section{My First Appendix}
\secttoc
\subsection{My First Subsection}
\subsection{My Second Subsection}

\section{My Second Appendix}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was wondering, can I do the same thing (that is, create a "local" table of contents) in two different appendices?

Comment: Just say `\secttoc` after another section as well.

Comment: Then the toc of the second appendix appears at the first appendix, while there is no toc at all at the second appendix.