# Using titletoc with ACM acmart style

Tags: table-of-contents, acm

The recent [acmart](http://www.sigplan.org/sites/default/files/acmart/current/acmart.cls) style (try [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acmart?lang=en) if that link is broken) doesn't seem to work properly with `titletoc`, producing an unwanted string of section names at the beginning of the table of contents:

[image]

I'm looking for output similar to that shown in the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171694/table-of-contents-within-appendix), which I can get by replacing `acmart` by `article`:

[image]

I have looked at other table-of-contents solutions, but I particularly like the output of `titletoc`, so I would like to get that working if possible.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\newcommand\DoToC{%
  \startcontents
  \printcontents{}{2}{\textbf{Contents}\vskip3pt\hrule\vskip5pt}
  \vskip3pt\hrule\vskip5pt
}

\begin{document}

\DoToC

\section{My First Section}
\section{My Second Section}

\begin{appendices}
\section{My First Appendix}
\DoToC
\subsection{My First Subsection}
\subsection{My Second Subsection}

\section{My Second Appendix}
\DoToC
\subsection{My First Subsection}
\subsection{My Second Subsection}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is that class file`acmart.cls` ?

Comment: See link at beginning of question.

Comment: Yes. Not Working and opening here.

Comment: Weird. Opens for me fine. Added a link to the CTAN package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, `acmart` loads `hyperref`.  Normally `hyperref`  redefines some `titletoc` internals to work.  However, since you now load `titletoc` after `hyperref`, it does not have a chance to do so.

This means you need to redefine them yourself.

This works:

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\makeatletter
  \def\ttl@Hy@steplink#1{%
    \Hy@MakeCurrentHrefAuto{#1*}%
    \edef\ttl@Hy@saveanchor{%
      \noexpand\Hy@raisedlink{%
        \noexpand\hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}%
        \noexpand\hyper@anchorend
        \def\noexpand\ttl@Hy@SavedCurrentHref{\@currentHref}%
        \noexpand\ttl@Hy@PatchSaveWrite
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \def\ttl@Hy@PatchSaveWrite{%
    \begingroup
      \toks@\expandafter{\ttl@savewrite}%
      \edef\x{\endgroup
        \def\noexpand\ttl@savewrite{%
          \let\noexpand\@currentHref
              \noexpand\ttl@Hy@SavedCurrentHref
          \the\toks@
        }%
      }%
    \x
  }%
  \def\ttl@Hy@refstepcounter#1{%
    \let\ttl@b\Hy@raisedlink
    \def\Hy@raisedlink##1{%
      \def\ttl@Hy@saveanchor{\Hy@raisedlink{##1}}%
    }%
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \let\Hy@raisedlink\ttl@b
  }%
\def\ttl@gobblecontents#1#2#3#4{\ignorespaces}%
\makeatother

\newcommand\DoToC{%
  \startcontents
  \printcontents{}{2}{\textbf{Contents}\vskip3pt\hrule\vskip5pt}
  \vskip3pt\hrule\vskip5pt
}

\begin{document}

\DoToC

\section{My First Section}
\section{My Second Section}

\begin{appendices}
\section{My First Appendix}
\DoToC
\subsection{My First Subsection}
\subsection{My Second Subsection}

\section{My Second Appendix}
\DoToC
\subsection{My First Subsection}
\subsection{My Second Subsection}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```