# Using tocstyle with ACM acmart style

Tags: hyperref, tocstyle, acmart, csname

The recent [`acmart`](http://www.sigplan.org/sites/default/files/acmart/current/acmart.cls) style (try [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acmart) if that link is broken) doesn't seem to work properly with [`tocstyle`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocstyle?lang=en). If I run `pdflatex` twice on the following document, the second run fails (see below).

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\tableofcontents
\section{Intro}
text
\end{document}
```

Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \@@par 
l.8 \tableofcontents
```

Maybe there's a fix similar to the one in the question about [`titletoc`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357265/using-titletoc-with-acm-acmart-style)? Unfortunately I don't know how find out which internals of `tocstyle` that `hyperref` is re-defining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it’s a good idea to monkey with `acmart`, which is supposed to be used for submissions to the ACM, hence with a well defined style (among the available choices).

The problem is that `tocstyle` should be loaded before `hyperref`, but the `acmart` class already loads it.

A workaround is to create a file named `acmart-preload-hook.tex` in the working directory containing

```
\let\LoadClassOrig\LoadClass
\renewcommand\LoadClass[2][]{%
  \LoadClassOrig[#1]{#2}%
  \usepackage{tocstyle}%
}
```

as suggested in `acmart`’s documentation, section 2.13.

Comment: Section 2.13 also says "If you decided to use this hook, you are on your own." I think I'll just stop using `tocstyle`.